# adding a new class using a for loop to determine which class specifically to add

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, flash, flash-cs5, addchild

I made this account to ask this question because researching strings and testing a whole ton of different things ended up with nothing working. You should be able to see what I am trying to do with this code piece here that is not working for me. If I hard type out "Level1" instead of "Level[i]" everything works fine.

```
for (var i = 0; i<=100; i++)
{
    if (levelOn == i)
    {
        var Lv:Level[i] = new Level[i];
        addChild(Lv)  
    }
}
```

I have 100 level files labeled "level1", "level2", etc in the project folder. I am trying to access a certain level via using a forloop to add a certain level to the screen (levelOn = 56 means the compiler would add the class "Level56" to the screen.)
I think I have the right idea but I cannot get it to work, all I get is this error

Line 24    1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before leftbracket.

If someone has a more efficient way of accessing a "level" in a application (where it has the same base class but minor differences) please send me in the right direction.

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Did you try something like `var LvClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("Level"+levelOn) as Class; var Lv = new LvClass();`?

Comment: This **var Lv:Level[i]** is incorrect, you are not supposed to declare variable type dynamically like that. You can go for generic or unspecified types like **var Lv:Object** or var Lv:* though.

Comment: @kaarto Hi, thanks for the reponse.

Comment: @kaarto Hi, thanks for the reponse.                                               
This commented out code works exactly how I need it                                                                                                       
//var Lv:Level1 = new Level1
//addChild(Lv)                but this one that suggested to do makes the error:  ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Level1 is not defined/
 at global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName()                                      It seems like it reads the "Level1" correctly but it doesn't recognize it. Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm that sounds odd. Same error if you try with `getDefinitionByName("Level1")`?

Comment: @kaarto Yes, same error.  var Lv:Level1 = new Level1
addChild(Lv)  still works but the getDefinitionByName("Level1")  code doesn't work still.

Comment: Double check that your library objects has both checkboxes set; "Export for ActionScript", and "Export in frame 1"

Comment: @kaarto yes, those are checked, and I know that is not the issue because I can add the class to the screen via: var Lv:Level1 = new Level1 addChild(Lv)     but as soon as I try to do : getDefinitionByName("Level1")  <---- this kind of method, it does not work. I think its a coding issue. I don't think action script supports something like this. Might have to go ahead and use 100 if statements in the code to solve this issue.

Comment: It does support it, so this is weird. But now, try typing `Level1;` before your getDefinitionByName -line.

Comment: @kaarto Sorry, I didn't understand what you wanted me to try. Can you be a bit more specific? Also I am coding this in the frame instead of a document class, maybe that has something to do with it possibly? (flash cs5.5)

Comment: I ment trying Short Notation, like [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-understanding-getdefinitionbyname--active-9945)

Comment: @kaarto Thank you for that source, that is exactly what was needed for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var i:int;
var Lv:Level[i] = new Level[i];
    addChild(Lv) 
for (i=0; i<100; i++){
    if(LevelOn=i)
}
```

Comment: sorry, this one didn't work. All I am trying to do is get the program to essentially run this piece of code :  var Lv:Level1 = new Level1
addChild(Lv)   which works perfectly. But instead of the "1" in front of the "Level", the "1" can change into any other number using math. The change of this number would allow access to different classes that are stored in the document folder. (such as Level1, Level2, Level3, etc. which all have their own tweaks and minor differences and can then be added as a child to the stage using code.) Any Ideas?